# Could not Add customer address using customer id using Magento-2 REST API

Tags: magento2, rest-api, curl-request

I am facing one issue while adding new address of a existing customer using its id. I am explaining my code below.

```
 <?php
include('db.php');
$response=array();
$adminUrl='http://magento-148486-425775.cloudwaysapps.com/index.php/rest/V1/integration/admin/token';
$ch = curl_init();
$data = array("username" => "raj", "password" => "raj@0987.");

$data_string = json_encode($data);                       
$ch = curl_init($adminUrl); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");                                                                     
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);                                                                  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);                                                                      
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
    'Content-Type: application/json',                                                                                
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))                                                                       
);       
$token = curl_exec($ch);
$email=$_POST['email'];
$company=$_POST['company'];
$first_name=$_POST['first_name'];
$last_name=$_POST['last_name'];
$mobile=$_POST['mobile'];
$street=$_POST['street'];
$city=$_POST['city'];
$state=$_POST['state'];
$pin=$_POST['pin'];
$country_id=$_POST['country_id'];
$user_id=$_POST['user_id'];
//echo $user_id;exit;
$sql=mysqli_query($conn,"select * from mobusers where id='".$user_id."'");
if(mysqli_num_rows($sql)){
    $row=mysqli_fetch_array($sql);
    $ent_id=$row['entity_id'];//customer's id
    $customerData = [
        'customer' => [
            'addresses' => [
                [
                    "id"=>$ent_id,
                    "firstname"=> $first_name,
                    "lastname"=> $last_name,
                    "company"=> $company,
                    "street"=> [
                    $street
                    ],
                    "city"=> $city,
                    "postcode"=> $pin,
                    "country_id"=> $country_id,
                    "telephone"=> $mobile
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ];
    $requestUrl='http://magento-148486-425775.cloudwaysapps.com/index.php/rest/V1/customers/'.$ent_id;
    //echo $requestUrl;exit;
    $ch = curl_init();
    $ch = curl_init($requestUrl); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($customerData));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json", "Authorization: Bearer " . json_decode($token))); 
    $result = curl_exec($ch); 

    $result = json_decode($result, 1);
    print_r($result);exit;
    if(!isset($result['message']) && $result > 0){
        $response['status']="Success";
        $response['msg']="Your addresse has been updated successfully.";
    }else{
        $response['status']="Error";
        $response['msg']="Failed!";
    }
    echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

Here I have already one existing customer and while registered he does not add any address. I have already the customer's id(`i.e-$ent_id(entity_id of customer entity table)`) which will be the parent ID of the address table. Using this ID I want to add this new address to address table. But in my case I am getting the following error.

```
Array
(
    [message] => Request does not match any route.
    [trace] => 
)
```

Here I need to add this address using this customer id.Please help me.

Comment: In Customer module this by this url of api is used for PUT method can you change your method from POST to PUT and then try once.

Comment: @CharulTyagi : I have already applied `PUT` method but its not updating anything.